# Drupal 7 - debugging hooks

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, hook, taxonomy

I am in the process of making my own implementation of `hook_taxonomy_term_insert($term)` using a module. This works fine because I can add the following:

```
drupal_set_message( 'todo', 'status' );
```

which will show up fine. However, how can I debug my hook? For example I would like to var_dump the `$term` and start coding from there. But how do I stop the redirect, so that I am able to print out messages?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) (development) module.  It is extremely helpful in debugging.  There is also an option to stop redirects so you can debug from there.